# Using the preorder and inorder sequence to rebuild a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I have write the following codes but every time I run the program it show the result

```
File "D:\study\ML\binaryTree.py", line 31, in buildTree
    root.left = self.buildTree(preorder[1:rootvalue],inorder[0:rootvalue-1])
File "D:\study\ML\binaryTree.py", line 30, in buildTree
    root = TreeNode(rootvalue)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`
```

It must be recursively solved and I really don't know what's the problem. The code I wrote:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left, self.right = None, None

class Solution:
    def buildTree(self, preorder, inorder):
        if preorder == None or inorder == None:
            return None
        if len(preorder) != len(inorder):
            return None

        length = len(preorder)
        rootvalue = 0
        for i in range(0,length):
            if inorder[i] == preorder[0]:
                rootvalue = i
                break
        if rootvalue == length-1 and inorder[rootvalue] != preorder[0]:
            return None
        root = TreeNode(rootvalue)
        root.left = self.buildTree(preorder[1:rootvalue],inorder[0:rootvalue-1])
        root.right = self.buildTree(preorder[rootvalue+1:length],inorder[rootvalue+1:length])
        print root.val,'->'
        return root
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sul = Solution()
    pre = [1,2,3]
    inorder = [2,1,3]
    sul.buildTree(pre,inorder)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code guarding against empty lists, so you have no base case for your recursion. Probably instead of your `preorder == None or inorder == None` tests, you want `if not preorder or not inorder` (since lists are "falsey" if they're empty).

Comment: Oh yes ! U are right,Thank you so much , make me realize the difference between [] and None.